# Whose Email(s) Should be Listed on Research Poster Presentations?

Tags: graduate-school, conference, etiquette, poster

If I make a conference poster as a graduate student, whose email address(es) should be included in the subtitle of the poster? Traditionally, I have always thought it should just be the PI's email, since they're the corresponding author, but I've seen a few posters where either the graduate student's email is either the only one listed or both the student and PIs' emails are listed (both the student and PI are listed as authors in both cases). As this is my first time preparing a professional research poster, I am wondering what the generally accepted etiquette for this is.

Comment: If a random viewer of the poster will be able to contact you by just knowing your name and affiliation (for example by a university website), you don't need to put any email address at all on the poster itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on standards within the field. In math or theoretical subfields, often all authors are considered equal and are corresponding authors (unless they don't want to be).

Personally though, so long as no one else in your group has a problem with it, I would include your email as well since it can be helpful for your professional development. I've definitely reached out to people who presented posters before via email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that people can contact you (and you should: you are the author of the poster, after all!), you will need to include your email address!